# Debug version only crash

Tags: c++, debugging, boost

I'm having a debug only crash. I'm using Eclipse's gdb.
If I'm not failing reading it, the crash seems to occur when passing an object (not by reference nor pointer) to an interface method, precisely when copying a "`many`" (`typedef std::list<boost::any> many;`) member during it's copy constructor called to send a copy to the method.
I'm not using debug builds for boost, nor other external builds, just for the code I'm compiling, so, could this be the cause?
Any other ideas at what may be the cause?

```
class Message {
public:
static const int MAX_LEVEL=5;
Message(int type=0, int destination=0);
virtual ~Message();

int type;
int destination[MAX_LEVEL];
int level;
many message;
};
```

And the crashing sector, inside `init()` on `Game3DWin`: (Even though I'm building in Debug mode, there's no _DEBUG define since I didn't build the Debug binaries for the libs)

```
bool Game3DWin::init(){
#ifdef _DEBUG
pluginsCfg = "lib/plugins_d.cfg";
resourcesCfg = "res/resources_d.cfg";
#elif OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
pluginsCfg = "lib/pluginsWin.cfg";
resourcesCfg = "res/resources.cfg";
#else
pluginsCfg = "lib/plugins.cfg";
resourcesCfg = "res/resources.cfg";
#endif
ogreRoot=boost::make_shared<Ogre::Root>(pluginsCfg, "config.cfg");
if(!(ogreRoot->restoreConfig() || ogreRoot->showConfigDialog())){
    return false;
}
window = ogreRoot->initialise(true, "Crewon CLASH!");
loadResourceCfgFile();

guiRenderer = &CEGUI::OgreRenderer::bootstrapSystem();
CEGUI::SchemeManager::getSingleton().create( "TaharezLook.scheme" );
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setDefaultFont( "DejaVuSans-10" );
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setDefaultMouseCursor( "TaharezLook", "MouseArrow" );
CEGUI::Window* myRoot = CEGUI::WindowManager::getSingleton().createWindow( "DefaultWindow", "_MasterRoot" );
CEGUI::System::getSingleton().setGUISheet( myRoot );

    CRengine::Message msg=CRengine::Message( (int)CRengine::MESSAGE_TYPE::INPUT_INIT );
msg.message.push_front(window);
this->broadcaster.lock()->receiveMessage( msg ); //Crash here
//Unreached code due to crash
}
```

broadcaster is a pointer to Messageable, an interface.

```
class Messageable {
public:
virtual ~Messageable() {};
virtual bool receiveMessage(CRengine::Message) = 0;
};
```

broadcaster initialization (factory method to be able to store a "this" smart pointer):

```
Game3DWin* Game3DWin::create(boost::shared_ptr<CRengine::Messageable> caster, int processType, int order){
Game3DWin* temp= new Game3DWin(processType, order);
temp->broadcaster=caster;
bool success=temp->init();
if(!success){
    delete temp;
    temp=NULL;
}else{
    temp->checkRoom(); }
return temp;
}
```

The above is called here:

```
bool MainManager::start( boost::shared_ptr<MainManager> thisMM ){
//Some code
    boost::shared_ptr<Game3DWin> win;
    win.reset( Game3DWin::create(thisMM, CRengine::MAIN_PROCESS_TYPES::PROCESS_GUI) );
//Some code
}
```

start() called from the main, which passes the pointer to MainManager

```
boost::shared_ptr<CRengine::MainManager> app =boost::make_shared<CRengine::MainManager>();
        app->start(app);
```

Message implementation:

```
Message::Message(int type, int destination): type(type), level(0){
for(int ii=0;ii<MAX_LEVEL;ii++){
     this->destination[ii]=-1;
}
this->destination[0]=destination;
}
Message::~Message() { }
```

`window` is `Ogre::RenderWindow*` from OGRE 3D open source rendering engine. I tried to cast it to `(int)` before pushing it into `many` in case it tried to call a destructor or something, but, still, same crash.

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: There, this is all that I think should be relevant without adding too much bloat. Message and Messageable are unedited actually. If you think more's needed, do tell.

Comment: Where do you initialize broadcaster? I assume it is a pointer to a subclass of Messageable right?

Comment: There it is. Yes, class MainManager : public Messageable

Comment: You can't assign weak pointers like that, you have to use a shared_ptr constructor or a lock(). And is broadcaster a shared_ptr? It has to be.

Comment: Is this going to call start() and produce a valid broadcaster?  
Game3DWin* temp= new Game3DWin(processType, order);
If it doesn't then that is why it crashes and if it does, it calls itself recursively for ever.

Comment: So, the first correction would be "temp->broadcaster=caster.lock();"? And broadcaster is: boost::weak_ptr<CRengine::Messageable> broadcaster;  that's why I call it's .lock() before doing receiveMessage(), otherwise there would be circular reference with MainManager.

Comment: Game3DWin is constructed through a factory method, static Game3DWin* create(...), so it doesn't loop creating itself.

Comment: My advice, change all the weak pointers for shared (even the parameters) and when you make it work, rethink the reasons for wanting weak pointers anyway.

Comment: Ok. I did that (eliminated the weak_ptr header, ran the compiler, and eliminated all the invalid weak_ptr errors with shared_ptr), and I still get the same crash...

Comment: Random style improvement: change `static const int MAX_LEVEL=5;` to `enum {MAX_LEVEL=5}`.  But that is just a personal preference.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was none of the aforementioned. It was caused by Eclipse being unable to clean. This was caused due to using "External Builder", mingw32-make.exe, which in the makefile ran a `del <Filelist>` and Windows7 seems to have some issue with this and it's parameters, so the `clean` did nothing.
Since I was working with `Debug` as active build, I got the crash due to lack of `clean`, but when I switched to `Release` it was unaffected since it had to mostly rebuild everything.
Manual delete of the contents of `<project>/Debug` and `<project>/Release` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment, too long to fit in a comment.

`Message` lacks an implemented constructor and destructor.  Either simplfy the class while confirming the problem still occurs, or expose that implementation to us.

`window` is a variable of unknown type.  As the `list` of `boost::any` that you are reporting as crashing contains the `window` type, knowing what it is may just be somewhat useful.

`this->broadcaster.lock()` will be a null `shared_ptr` if the `weak_ptr` has gone away.  Always, always, always do `shared_ptr<foo> pFoo = this->broadcaster.lock();` then use `pFoo` (or whatever name) after checking that it is valid (evaluating it in a `bool`ean context).

`boost::weak_ptr<CRengine::Messageable> caster` -- do you not know if this exists?  You probably want a `boost::shared_ptr` here, so that the caster is at least known to exist during creation of the Game3DWin.

Same here: `boost::weak_ptr<MainManager> thisMM` -- probably should be a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: True all that. And is is clear that broadcaster is not valid at the crash.

Comment: `thisMM` points to itself. Wouldn't this cause circular reference and make it undeleteable? I need to keep it as a smart pointer because it passes itself to member objects, like `Game3Dwin` is. And it keeps a `Game3DWin shared_ptr`... if this `Game3DWin` has another `shared_ptr` back to the `MainManager`, wouldn't that be another circular reference? (That's why I thought I had to use `weak_ptr`)

Comment: Changed all weak_ptr to shared_ptr, and did a `this->broadcaster.get()` output before the crashing call, the outs: `Broadcaster=0x2d2fb0c` and I didn't quite get how to check it's valid, but outputted a `(bool)this->broadcaster` which returned `Broadcaster=1`

Comment: Update the code to reflect the current state of the problem please!  Oh, and pare `init` down so that it only does what you show it doing.

Comment: I couldn't pare `init` without making it unrunnable (since it includes functions to set up the window), so instead, I posted all the missing code from before the crash. So, there's the updated code.

Comment: While debugging, I get `warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for CRengine::Message value` several times, if it gives any lead.

Comment: I just ran the clean command on Eclipse, and putting attention to it's output I found that every single time it wasn't executing (error with the args). Did a manual delete of the object files, and now it doesn't crash in either debug or release. It seems that could be the actual root of all problems, object files getting linked weirdly?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It now works correctly in both debug and release.